# Is PHP's password_verify() safe against extremely long passwords (DoS attack)?

Tags: php, c, security, hash

**The general attack scenario:**

In 2013 Django had a general vulnerability as an attacker could create extremely intense CPU calculations via very large passwords [[see the security notice here](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/)]. I'm unsure if this is still possible when using PHP's *password_verify()* and other password-hashing methods without any further checks.

**The PHP documentation says:**

> Using the PASSWORD_BCRYPT for the algo parameter, will result in the password parameter being truncated to a maximum length of 72 characters.

**But, PHP's code MAYBE says something different:**

The [C code behind PHP 5.5.0's *password_verify()* function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/ext/standard/password.c#L273) however does not limit the passed argument directly (maybe on a deeper level inside the bcrypt algorithm ?). Also, the [PHP implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) does not limit the argument.

**The question:**

Is *password_verify()* (and other functions of the same function set) vulnerable against DoS via maxed out POST parameters ? Please also consider site-wide config situations of POST upload sizes much larger than 4MB.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The password is limited to 72 characters internally in the crypt algorithm.

To see why, let's look at `crypt()`'s source: [ext/standard/crypt.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cbc785dc8c89a5ff085909e555d677d4d8d7c9a1/ext/standard/crypt.c#L150)

```
    } else if (
            salt[0] == '$' &&
            salt[1] == '2' &&
            salt[3] == '$') {
        char output[PHP_MAX_SALT_LEN + 1];

        memset(output, 0, PHP_MAX_SALT_LEN + 1);

        crypt_res = php_crypt_blowfish_rn(password, salt, output, sizeof(output));
        if (!crypt_res) {
            ZEND_SECURE_ZERO(output, PHP_MAX_SALT_LEN + 1);
            return NULL;
        } else {
            result = zend_string_init(output, strlen(output), 0);
            ZEND_SECURE_ZERO(output, PHP_MAX_SALT_LEN + 1);
            return result;
        }
```

The `password` field is a simple `char*` field. So there's no length information. All that's passed is a normal pointer.

So if we follow that through, we'll eventually land at [`BF_set_key`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cbc785dc8c89a5ff085909e555d677d4d8d7c9a1/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c#L551).

The important part is the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < BF_N + 2; i++) {
    tmp[0] = tmp[1] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        tmp[0] <<= 8;
        tmp[0] |= (unsigned char)*ptr; /* correct */
        tmp[1] <<= 8;
        tmp[1] |= (BF_word_signed)(signed char)*ptr; /* bug */

        if (j)
            sign |= tmp[1] & 0x80;
        if (!*ptr)
            ptr = key;
        else
            ptr++;
    }
    diff |= tmp[0] ^ tmp[1]; /* Non-zero on any differences */

    expanded[i] = tmp[bug];
    initial[i] = BF_init_state.P[i] ^ tmp[bug];
}
```

`BF_N` is defined to be 16. So the outer loop will loop 18 times (`BF_N + 2`).

The inner loop will loop 4 times. 4 * 18 == 72.

And there you have it, only 72 characters of the key will be read. No more.

### Note

Now, there's an interesting side-effect to that algorithm. Because it uses C-Strings (strings terminated by a `\0` null byte), it's impossible for it to use anything past `\0`. So a password that contains a null-byte will lose any entropy past it. Example: http://3v4l.org/Y6onV

Comment: I don't know if you'll see this, but that URL http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/crypt.c#202 doesn't seem to load (anymore).

Comment: Then again; any link with `lxr.php.net`.